# Execute same function in all Controllers on the same event - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently experiencing a problem with Bootstrap Modal, when changing views through the URL. ReloadOnSearch is disabled.

If I'm on a view such as:

> blah.com/examples/1

and open up a Modal with a faded backdrop, then change the URL to change views such as:

> blah.com/examples/2

the Modal window will close, but the faded backdrop will remain, and disable interaction to the web page.

I'm wondering if there is a way to define one function, which will programmatically remove the faded backdrop, which will execute on URL change, regardless of the controller in use.

Though the cause of the issue is due to AngularJS, the solution doesn't need to use AngularJS.

Comment: I had same issue, the solution is to remove that overlay class while your hashurl change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue, the solution is to remove that overlay class while your hashurl change

```
    window.onhashchange = function() {
    $(".lean-overlay").fadeOut(500); // whatever class name your overlay has
     }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Didn't realise there was a 'onhashchange' event!

Answer (score 1):

Use the event `onhashchange` to hide all modals on screen using the proper hide method:

```
window.onhashchange = function(event) {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');

    // You can even add some tests based on the new and old URL
    console.log('new URL', event.newURL);
    console.log('old URL', event.oldURL);
}
```